# Reducing the intensity resolution of grey-level image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to take an image with grey-level resolution 2^8, and then iterate to reduce the intensity resolution of each image to 2^k, for k=7, 6, …, 2, 1. I would like to display the original image together with the reduced intensity resolution images on a single figure.

I have tried to implement this, however, the reduced intensity resolution images do not appear in the correct order from the original image. The title for each image is also not displayed.

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP0u2.png');

k = 8
while (k > 0)
 reducedImage = uint8((single(img)/256)*2^k);
 subplot(3, 3, k);
 imshow(reducedImage, [0 255]);
 title('Grey-level resolution 2^ %s',k);
 k = k - 1;
end
```

The program should display the  original image in the top-left most corner, followed 2^k, for k=7, 6, …, 2, 1, with the correct title. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at the lena image you posted. Have you been really working with this image as a start or is it already a result of your color compression? I am asking because the histogram of the image certainly looks like there is not much more left to compress. So I would advise to use a different image source, e.g. [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/png/lena.png)

```
img = imread('https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/png/lena.png');
```

Then the first step is to make sure the image is using the full dynamic range of uint8:

```
min_img = min(img(:));
max_img = max(img(:));
img_norm = (img - min_img) * (256 / double(max_img - min_img));
```

To be on the safe side, lets have a look at the images and their histograms:

```
figure
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(img)
subplot(2,2,2)
hist(img(:))
subplot(2,2,3)
imshow(img_norm)
subplot(2,2,4)
hist(img_norm(:))
```

Since the image already fills the range pretty well, there is not much change in the histogram. But try this with the original image source you posted and you will see what I meant:

[image: OP's Lena Version]

Compared to the alternative Lena version I provided

[image]

Now that we have made sure we have a sensible image version to start with, lets tackle the quantization step issue: The main idea is to

1. convert the image to float and normalize it to the interval [0,1]
2. multiply it with the number of desired quantization steps (e.g. 128 for the second step)
3. round (floor) the the values and convert back to uint8

In this way, all values between the number of quantization steps are compressed into one by the rounding operation.

```
k = 8
figure
while (k > 0)
 target_levels = 2^k;
 target_compr_factor = 256 / target_levels;
 reduced_image = uint8(floor(double(img)/256 * target_levels) * target_compr_factor);
 subplot(3, 3, k);
 imshow(reduced_image, [0 255]);
 title(['Grey-level resolution 2^',num2str(k)]);
 k = k - 1;
end
```

[image: lena_quantization]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a bunch for posting this. I was able to figure out my assignment.

A few comments:

The following line of code:

```
reduced_image = uint8(floor(double(img)/256 * target_levels) * target_compr_factor);
```

Didn't make sense to me, as by punching this numbers on my calc I always got 256, **if you could elaborate on what was going on here I would greatly appreciate it.**

Finally, my code ended up looking like this

```
im221=imread('fig221.tif');

figure (3),
k=7;
while (k>0)
    intensity_level = 2^k;  %calculation of intensity level
    current_compression = 256/intensity_level; % this value will be used to set the new range for display
    im221_reduced = uint8(floor(double(im221)/intensity_level));
    subplot(3, 3, k);
    l = current_compression-1;
    imshow(im221_reduced, [0,l]);
    title(['\fontsize{16}Intensity Level=', num2str(current_compression)]);
    k = k-1;
end
```

I was asked to reduce intensity while adjusting the range of intensity for display accordingly. My out was the following:

[image: Image - Radiology Intensity Levels]